# Dataset for segmenting multivariate time series

Tags: data-request, biology

I am doing a project on segmenting a multivariate time series into intervals with predominant trends. So I am looking for a multivariate time series dataset preferably biological data with high dimensionality (genes, proteins, metabolites monitored over time ) and one which can be broken down into atleast 4-5 different segments each representing some major event.

Comment: please check the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html), which labels data sets based on analysis type